# Uploading songs from website to database and then to Spotify

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, sqlite, selenium

My Python program parses songs from a website, corrects song titles and artists with the Last.fm API, searches for the spotify uri using the Spotify API, stores all the information in a SQLite database and then uploads it into a Spotify playlist with the Spotify API.

I would like to make the program object oriented and need some advice on how to do that.
Some general python advice would also be useful.

I have a separate config.py file with all the needed API variables.

**scraper.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# import config file
import config

# import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import urllib.request as urllib
import sys
import time
import re
import sqlite3

# webdriver libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# spotipy library
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

# import pylast
import pylast 

# song class holds information about each song
class Song:
    artist = None
    song = None
    spotify_uri = None

    def __init__(self, artist, song, spotify_uri):
        self.artist = artist
        self.song = song
        self.spotify_uri = spotify_uri

    def printSong(self):
        print(self.artist, '-', self.song, ', Uri:', self.spotify_uri)

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Get Date of latest sunday
## 
## @return formatted date of last sunday as yyyymmdd
#
def getSundayDate():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    sun_offset = (today.weekday() - 6) % 7
    sunday_of_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=sun_offset)
    sunday_date = sunday_of_week.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    return sunday_date

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## URL Pattern
##
## https://fm4.orf.at/player/20190120/SSU
## URL pattern:
## /yyyymmdd/SSU
## /20190120/SSU
## SSU is just Sunny Side Up the show from 10am till 1pm
## URL pattern changes ever day, we need to change it every week, 
## to only get sundays
## 
## @return concatenated URL of website
def getURLPattern():
    return 'https://fm4.orf.at/player/' + getSundayDate() + '/SSU'

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Get html source from page specified by page_url
## 
## @return html source as beautiful soup object
#
def getHtmlFromPage():
    page_URL = getURLPattern()

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("media.volume_scale", "0.0")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=profile)

    driver.get(page_URL)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
        'broadcast-items-list')))
    time.sleep(1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    driver.quit()
    return soup

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## remove bad characters from list 
## 
## @param list, list with elements to check
#
def sanitize(strList):
    regex_remove = r'([^A-z\s\däöüÄÖÜß-][\\\^]?)'
    regex_ft = r'(ft\.?([^\n]\s?\w*)+)'

    # check for bad characters
    for i in range(len(strList)):
        strList[i] = re.sub(regex_remove, "", str(strList[i]))
        strList[i] = re.sub(regex_ft, "", strList[i])

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## print music 
## 
## @param lists to print
#
def printMusic(interpreter_list, title_list):
    for element in range(len(interpreter_list)):
        print(interpreter_list[element] + " : " + title_list[element])

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## parse html
## 
## @param lists to write results to
#
def parseHtml(interpreter_list, title_list):
    soup = getHtmlFromPage()

    # find all interpreter in playlist
    interpreter = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "interpreter"})

    # find all titles in playlist
    title = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "title"})

    # Check for errors
    if (len(interpreter) != len(title)):
        raise Exception("The amount of interpreters don't correspond" +
                "to the amount of titles.")
    if (len(interpreter) == 0):
        raise Exception("No FM4 music playlist found in given url") 

    for element in range(len(interpreter)):
        interpreter_list.append(interpreter[element].text)
        title_list.append(title[element].text)

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## create Token with given credentials
## 
## @return authentication token
#
def getToken():
    # authetication token
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(config.USERNAME, config.SCOPE, config.CLIENT_ID, 
            config.CLIENT_SECRET, config.REDIRECT_URI)

    if token:
        return token
    else:
        raise Exception("Could not get authentication token from spotify!")

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## search track and get spotify uri
## 
## @param token, authentication token
## @param interpreter && title, strings containing track info
## @return uri string
#
def getUri(spotify_Obj, interpreter, title):
    result = spotify_Obj.search(q=interpreter + ' ' + title)

    if (result != None):
        if (len(result['tracks']['items']) != 0):
            track_id = result['tracks']['items'][0]['uri']
            uri = str(track_id)
            return uri

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## correct artist name and track title with lastFm api
## 
## @param1 artist_name, name of artist to correct
## @param2 title_name, title name to correct
## @return track_corrected, corrected Track object
#
def getTrackInfo(artist_name, track_name):
    # network authentication
    last_Fm = getLastFmNetworkAuth()

    # declare artist_name as artist object
    artist = last_Fm.get_artist(artist_name)
    # correct artist name
    artist_corrected_name = artist.get_correction()

    track = last_Fm.get_track(artist_corrected_name, track_name)
    track_corrected_name = track.get_correction()

    trackInfo = pylast.Track(artist_corrected_name, track_corrected_name, 
            last_Fm)
    return trackInfo

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## get last fm network authentication
## 
## @return network authentication token
#
def getLastFmNetworkAuth():
    network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(config.LASTFM_API_KEY, config.LASTFM_API_SECRET)
    return network

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## parse music items from website, put them into a list, sanitize lists, 
## correct artist names and song titles with last.fm API and save list in a 
## sqlite database for further usage
## 
## @return network authentication token
#
def parseTracksIntoSongClassList(song_list):
    # lists containing the Interpreter and title
    interpreter_list = []
    title_list = []

    # fill lists with results
    parseHtml(interpreter_list, title_list)

    print(datetime.datetime.now(), "Done parsing html")

    # remove bad characters from lists
    sanitize(interpreter_list)
    sanitize(title_list)

    # get Token and create spotify object
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(getToken())

    # correct artist and title names
    for element in range(len(interpreter_list)):
        track_info = getTrackInfo(interpreter_list[element], 
                title_list[element])

        title = str(track_info.get_name())
        artist = str(track_info.get_artist())

        if (title != artist):
            if (title is not None):
                title_list[element] = title
            if (artist is not None):
                interpreter_list[element] = artist
        else:
            title_list[element] = title_list[element]
            interpreter_list[element] = interpreter_list[element]

        # get spotify uri for song
        spotify_uri = getUri(sp, interpreter_list[element], title_list[element]) 

        if (spotify_uri != None and len(spotify_uri) != 0):
            track_uri = str(spotify_uri)
            song_list.append(Song(interpreter_list[element], 
                title_list[element], track_uri))

    print(datetime.datetime.now(), "Done parsing songs")

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## insert new songs to database, checks for duplicates and ignores them
## 
## @param song_list, list containing songs which need to be inserted 
## into database
#
def updateDatabase(song_list):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('SongDatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # date to insert into table
    today = datetime.date.today()                                                                             
    today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs 
            (SongID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, artist_name TEXT, song_name TEXT, 
            spotify_uri TEXT, UploadDate TIMESTAMP, Uploaded INTEGER, 
            UNIQUE(artist_name, song_name, spotify_uri) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)''')

    for item in range(len(song_list)):
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO songs 
        (artist_name, song_name, spotify_uri, UploadDate, Uploaded) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)''', (song_list[item].artist, song_list[item].song, 
            song_list[item].spotify_uri, today, 0))

    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), "Done updating Database")

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## copy Uris from song_list into new list
##
## @param song_list, list containing songs which get copied into new list
## @return track_list, list containing all song uris
#
def getUrisList(song_list):
    uri_list = []

    for song in range(len(song_list)):
        uri_list.append(song_list[song].spotify_uri)
    print(uri_list)
    return uri_list

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Main part of the program
## get html and parse important parts into file
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # list to fill with corrected songs 
    song_list = []

    # parse songs into song_list
    parseTracksIntoSongClassList(song_list)

    # insert song_list into database
    updateDatabase(song_list)
```

**dataManager.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# import config file
import config

import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

# spotipy library
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## create Token with given credentials
## 
## @return authentication token
#
def getToken():
    # authetication token
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(config.USERNAME, config.SCOPE, config.CLIENT_ID, 
            config.CLIENT_SECRET, config.REDIRECT_URI)
    return token

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## insert new songs to database, checks for duplicates and ignores them
## 
## @param song_list, list containing songs to be inserted into database
#
def uploadSongsToSpotify():
    # declare db name
    database_name = 'SongDatabase.db'

    # spotify auth token
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(getToken())
    if sp:
        # spotify username
        username = config.USERNAME
        # spotify ide of playlist
        playlist_id = config.PLAYLIST_ID

        conn = sqlite3.connect(database_name)
        c = conn.cursor()

        c.execute("""SELECT spotify_uri FROM songs WHERE (Uploaded = 0)""")

        # save query results in tuple
        data = c.fetchall()

        # save uris in list, for spotipy
        uri_list = []
        for item in range(len(data)):
            uri_list.append(str(data[item][0]))

        print(uri_list)

        # upload uri_list to spotify
        # check for empty list
        if (len(uri_list) != 0):
            sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, uri_list)

            # set Uploaded values in database to 1
            c.execute("""UPDATE songs SET Uploaded = ? WHERE Uploaded = ?""", (1, 0))
            conn.commit()

        else:
            raise Exception("There aren't any new songs in database, songs were already uploaded")

        c.close()

    else:
        raise Exception("Could not get token from spotify API")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uploadSongsToSpotify()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some simple suggestions after a first look at `scraper.py`:

1. `class Song` defines a method called `printSong`. Don't do this. Instead, use the dundermethod `__str__` (and maybe `__repr__`) to define a mechanism to "stringify" the song, and then let the normal `print` function handle it:

   print(str(song))  # or ...
   print(repr(song))
2. Your `getSundayDate` computes the date of the appropriate Sunday, then returns it as a string. Instead, return the date object. Let the caller handle formatting the string, since the caller is `getUrlPattern` which does nothing but format strings...
3. Throughout your code you have these giant banner comments introducing your functions. Get rid of them, and put the descriptive text inside a docblock comment. This is why docblocks exist in Python:

   **No!**

   ```
   ##------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ## remove bad characters from list 
   ## 
   ## @param list, list with elements to check
   #
   def sanitize(strList):
   ```

   **Yes.**

   ```
   def sanitize(strList):
       """Remove bad characters from list.

       @param strList,    list with elements to check.
       """
   ```
4. Don't raise `Exception` objects. Class `Exception` is the base class of the standard error types. If you have to install a block to catch what you're raising, you are going to have to do `except Exception:` or maybe just `except:`, and that's no good. Either create your own exception class, like `class SongException(Exception): ;pass` or use the standard types (`IndexError`, `ValueError`, and `TypeError` for the most part).
5. In `parseHtml` you do this:

   ```
   for element in range(len(interpreter)):
       interpreter_list.append(interpreter[element].text)
       title_list.append(title[element].text)
   ```

   Written like a true Java programmer! But this isn't Java. So watch this video first: [Loop Like a Native](https://youtu.be/EnSu9hHGq5o) by Ned Batchelder. There are a couple of ways to rewrite this loop. You could zip the two source lists together, unpack them into a tuple, and operate on them:

   ```
   for interp, elt in zip(interpreter, element):
       interpreter_list.append(interp.text)
       element_list.append(elt.text)
   ```

   Or you could use a comprehension to iterate over each list separately to generate the text values, and use the `list.extend` method to implicitly `.append` each element of a sequence:

   ```
   interpreter_list.extend((elt.text for elt in interpreter))
   element_list.extend((elt.text for elt in element))
   ```

   Have some of this Python-flavored Cool-aid! It's quite delicious... ;-)
6. You define `getToken` in both source files. I'm not sure what that's about...

Looking at your `dataManager.py` file, it's quite short. I'd suggest that you just roll both files into a single source file.

Your post title asks how you can make your code more object-oriented. I don't think you need to do that, and I don't think you should try. You are writing a program that is very procedural: do this, then do that, next do the other, and finally store things here. That's not a good match for OO code, especially since the elements in question are all different. I encourage you to focus on using simple functions to ensure that you have good separation of concerns and encapsulation. I would also suggest visiting the documentation for Python's "magic methods" (aka dundermethods), and sitting through the Batchelder video I linked. There's a huge amount of Python mastery in that one 30-minute presentation.